# Issues installing Vicuna 13B

Tags: llama-index

I've been using the installation guide https://github.com/vicuna-tools/vicuna-installation-guide and BING assistant to try get me through installing Vicuna 13B on my Ubuntu PC, but seem to be banging my head against errors. I now believe I have what I need, but on trying to download the Vicuna Model from the installation guide, I get the following message:

```
wget --user=morgemilamaame --ask-password https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/vicuna-13B-1.1-GPTQ-4bit-128g-GGML/resolve/main/vicuna-13B-1.1-GPTQ-4bit-128g.GGML.bin
Password for user ‘morgemilamaame’: 
--2023-05-06 19:35:44--  https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/vicuna-13B-1.1-GPTQ-4bit-128g-GGML/resolve/main/vicuna-13B-1.1-GPTQ-4bit-128g.GGML.bin
Resolving huggingface.co (huggingface.co)... 18.154.41.66, 18.154.41.27, 18.154.41.125, ...
Connecting to huggingface.co (huggingface.co)|18.154.41.66|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authentication selected: Bearer realm="Authentication required", charset="UTF-8"
Reusing existing connection to huggingface.co:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-05-06 19:35:44 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I've also tried downloading from https://huggingface.co/vicuna/vicuna-13b/resolve/main/vicuna-13b.onnx with the same result. Any ideas?